# Why does this only read n-1 strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management

I am trying to write a program that reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout`
an array of strings of different lengths, but my program only reads `n-1` strings, although I specifically told it to read `n`.
Here is what I have come up so far:

```
int main()
{
    char **vectorschar;
    int n, i;
    char c;

    printf("How many strings will you read? : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    vectorschar = (char**)calloc(n, sizeof(char*));

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        vectorschar[i] = (char*)calloc(30, sizeof(char));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        gets(vectorschar[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        puts(vectorschar[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Could you please point me in the right direction? I am still learning about the way strings, IO and memory work in C so sorry if the question is silly and obvious.

Comment: Q: What key did you press immediately *after* entering the number of strings you're about to enter? And did you *remotely* consider some form of minimal debugging in this before posting here? (by minimal I mean a simple `printf()` or `puts()` in your `gets()` loop, which would have immediately told you the first string was empty). And unrelated, **stop using `gets()`**; it is so evil it is no longer part of the standard library.

Comment: @WhozCraig ...b.but debugging is really hard!  You have to think about stuff, run a debugger, log stuff, make notes etc and none of it is as much fun as coding.  Why bother if you can con someone else into doing it?

Comment: @Martin James I am in my first year of college, don't go hard on me mate, nobody has ever taught me how to use a debugger and most times I've tried I couldn' t figure it out.So if you could stop being sarcastic that would be great.Thanks for answering though.Plus it's my first time programming so I guess it would be nice to stop acting like I am an expert programmer making mistakes like this.

Comment: And yes I did think about an empty string, but again that's why I asked this question.i had hoped people in this part of science aren't so hard on new kids on the block.@WhozCraig I wouldnt use it but it was the simplest way of reading a string and it's what I've been advised to use

Comment: @andrei985 Recommend never using `gets()`.  Anytime code has IO troubles and is using `gets()` and `scanf()`, it is time to quit using those two.  `fgets()` and `getline()` are much better user IO alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the line

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

is executed, the newline character, `'\n'`, is left on the stream. It is used by the first call to `gets()`.

You can skip the newline by using:

```
scanf("%d%*[^\n]",&n);
getchar();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to flush an `stdin` stream to avoid `'\n'` character hitting your `gets()` call.
You can do it by adding `\n` to your `scanf()` call like this:

```
scanf("%d\n", &n);
```

EDIT: And yes, `scanf()` is much more preferable than `gets()`.

EDIT2: As [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) pointed below, it'll only work properly if input format is respected. Otherwise, all non-formated data before `\n` character will still remain in the buffer, affecting your `gets()` call. To avoid it, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27449984/4349614) example.

Comment: `scanf("%d\n", &n);` will consume the newline and _all_ following white-space.  `scanf()` will not return until some non-white-space is detected after the number - which is put back into `stdin` for subsequent IO.